# OleDBCommands: executing two commands and checking

Tags: vb.net, oledbcommand

I am trying to perform some OLEDB commands between a list of dictionary values and an access database. I am wondering if it is possible to check if one column in the access database matches the key of a dictionary, if you find the key that matches check the keyvalue in the dictionary to the access database quantity in another column. I am just wondering if this is possible since I am new to the SQL in vb.net commands.

I wanted to run these two queries but I am not sure if this is even possible. I tried to find some documents on this but I came out short. Anything would help!

```
sqlQry = "SELECT Column1 FROM [Table] WHERE Column1 = '" & Key & "' "

sqlQry = "SELECT Column2 FROM [Table] WHERE Column2 < " & Value & " "
```

Comment: A basic bit of Sql being

    `SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE Column1 = key AND Column2 < value`

Comment: What you want to run is possible. You can merge the two statements like I have done above if it makes sense to look at the database just once. The logic you are describing is an `IF` only condition, not `IF...ELSE...`. My comment above works great for an `IF` only condition. Two separate ones would be useful in an `IF...ELSE...` situation

Comment: A SQL `WHERE` clause is just a Boolean expression like any other. I don't know about where you're from but I learned about Boolean logic in maths class at school fairly early on. It's simple stuff: True, False, And, Or. We all apply logic every day so it doesn't take much for someone who thinks they are up to programming to formalise that logic and write a Boolean expression. If you can write an `If` statement in VB then you can write a `WHERE` clause in SQL because they both implement the same Boolean logic.

Comment: I know how to do the logic, but I keep getting the following error when I work with any comparison between integer values: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)"